# Silverlight 4 Binding ContentPresenter Content to Property MVVM Light

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I user MVVM Light toolkit and Silverlight 4 and I want to make a little learning project. My web application should consist of few pages which I will show in a content presenter. In my VM I have a property ActualPage. To set this property I generate a new instance of dem ViewModelLocator and set the property:

```
ViewModelLocator loc = new ViewModelLocator();
ActualPage = loc.LoginVM;
```

But if I start this project, even if I don't bind the contentpresenter to the property, Expression Blend 4 and Internet Explorer and Visual Studio crashes if I open this page with the VM...

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found a solution here:
http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Using-Blend-4-s-new-built-in-TransitionEffects-in-Navigation-and-MVVM-applications.aspx

But I wonder if this can be done easier, I think in Silverlight it's very complicated in relation to WPF with the  property?

Dominik